# NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, removechild

straight to the point:

```
function dell(a) {
    var id = a.split('');
    var rs_array = ["nr", "ps", "aan", "des", "subs", "del"];
    var r_array = ["artnr", "ps", "aan", "des", "subtots", "del"];
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) //ligt aan nummer
    {
        var regels = document.getElementById(rs_array[i]);
        regels.removeChild(document.getElementById(r_array[i] + id[3]));
    }
}
```

With this code im trying to detele some input elements

```
for r = 0 to a_rows-1 step 1%>
<tr id="regels">
    <td width="auto" id="nr"> 
        <input type="text" name="artid" id="artnr<%=r%>" value="<%=records(1,r)%>" size="6">
    </td>
    <td id="ps">
        <input type="text" name="ps" id="ps<%=r%>" onfocus="this.blur()" value="<%=records(2,r)%>" size="7">
    </td>
    <td id="aan">
        <input type="text" name="aan" id="aan<%=r%>" onkeyup="sub(this.id,this.value);count()"  value="<%=records(3,r)%>" size="2">
    </td>
    <td id="des">
        <input type="text" name="omschr" id="des<%=r%>" value="<%=records(4,r)%>" size="50">
    </td>
    <td id="subs">
        <input type="text" name="subtots" id="subtots<%=r%>" onfocus="this.blur()" value="<%=records(5,r)%>"  size="7">
    </td>
    <td id="del">
        <div id="del<%=r%>" onclick="dell(this.id)" style="cursor:pointer;border:1px black solid;font-size:20px">-</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<% next
```

This comes out of the database of mine. I'm trying to delete the input elements by giving them a id with a number.
The strange thing is: I can delete the first row, but after that it says: '`NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8`' when i try to delete another one.

Please help me. If you need more info about my code or something, you can ask it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a lot easier not to hardcode the parent element. Get the parent straight from the original element reference:

```
function dell(a) {
    var id = a.split('');
    var r_array = ["artnr", "ps", "aan", "des", "subtots", "del"];
    for (var i = 0; i < r_array.length; i++) {
        var element = document.getElementById(r_array[i] + id[3]);
        if (element) {
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, i will try it. --> Thank you so much, finally got what i wanted. Thanks!! One last thing: can you explain what parentNode does? Why it works now?

Comment: @siroj No problem :) Well, `parentNode` gets its immediate parent - it's an easy way without having to hardcode or figure out what the parent element is. `removeChild` works on children, so you need to work with parents and children, never ancestors and descendants. Here's some info on it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.parentNode